# Php openssl_pkey_new() throw error when creating ECC keys

Tags: php

```
$keyPair = openssl_pkey_new(array(
        "curve_name" => prime256v1,
        "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
    ));

openssl_pkey_export($keyPair,$private_key);

print_r($private_key)
```

The key will still be generated, however there will be an error

> Warning: Use of undefined constant prime256v1 - assumed 'prime256v1'
>   (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   GenPrivateKey.php

-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY----- MHcCAQEEIJTOhwzhTFjizqUyDwjh5eZcLBxyvcSG3WYze3HLWzrfoAoGCCqGSM49 AwEHoUQDQgAEGbzAL8sbxkb99V18s4+m04+v3k3QKhmTB3t4XKkGyAHPzycwkFu2 k+JI1YDSoJeMvVyZB8Pd/5GsOzFUM4cFYA== -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

Does anyone know why and how to get rid of this warning?

Thanks

Comment: `prime256v1` need to be either `"prime256v1"` or may be a variable `$prime256v1` (but for me this is not the case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on documentation of [openssl_pkey_new()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php)

> ***Description***
>
> resource openssl_pkey_new ([ array $configargs ] )
>
> ***Parameters***
>
> *configargs*
>
> You can finetune the key generation (such as
>   specifying the number of bits) using configargs. See [openssl_csr_new()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-new.php)
>   for more information about configargs.

either it needs to be like:-

```
$keyPair = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    "curve_name" => 'prime256v1',
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
));
```

or:-

```
$curve_names = openssl_get_curve_names(); //get all curve names
$keyPair = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    "curve_name" => $curve_names[19], //use your one
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
));
```

Reference:- [openssl_get_curve_names](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-curve-names.php)

NOTE:- Open this link [openssl_csr_new()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-new.php)  and you can see below things:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir, both of your methods work great. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @FoMM  glad to help you :):)